# Trying to figure out how to use "Date()"s for an assignment

Tags: java, date

Basically, I need to make the `closeDate = null` and the `openDate` the current date. Using latest version of Java SDK and netbeans.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Task {

    Date openDate = new Date();
    Date closeDate = new Date();
    public int taskType;

    public Task(int taskType)
    {   
        this.taskType = taskType;
    }

    static void setOpenDate(Date openDate)
    {

    }

    static void setCloseDate(Date closeDate)
    {

    }

    static void setTaskType(int taskType)
    {

    }

    static int getTaskType()
    {
    }

    static Date getOpenDate()
    {
        return openDate;
    }

    static Date getCloseDate()
    {
        return closeDate;
    }

}
```

This is what I have. I'm losing my mind on other parts of this painful assignment, but I just need some form of clarity for something.

Comment: Whatcha need help clarifying my dude? The whole thing or do you have a single point of confusion?

Comment: (1) Indent your code properly. (2) What's the problem with making `closeDate = null`? (3) Did you have to use the old `Date` class? There are newer classes for handling time. (4) Did you search? Googling easily gives many answer.

Comment: You did not specify any question, but it seems you have a problem with static methods. Your getter/setter methods are static while fields you are trying to get/set are not!

Comment: If open date and close date are just dates (without time of day), use `LocalDate`. If the time needs to be recorded too, use `Instant`. `Date` is long outdated and poorly designed, you won’t want to use it if you can avoid it.

Comment: Poor title. Edit to specify you particular technical issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "static" modifier from methods and create setter and getter instance level. You can use Java 8 `LocalDate` for date and time but I don't think you need it for you current purpose.

You can initialize instance variables as defined in below code snippet, Below code will initialize the open date as current date and close date as null once you create new object of Task

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Task {

    private Date openDate  = new Date();
    private Date closeDate = null;
    public  int  taskType;

    public Task(int taskType) {
        this.taskType = taskType;
    }

    public Date getOpenDate() {
        return openDate;
    }

    public void setOpenDate(Date openDate) {
        this.openDate = openDate;
    }

    public Date getCloseDate() {
        return closeDate;
    }

    public void setCloseDate(Date closeDate) {
        this.closeDate = closeDate;
    }

    public int getTaskType() {
        return taskType;
    }

    public void setTaskType(int taskType) {
        this.taskType = taskType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, that helped out so much. 
+Rep

Comment: public class UpdateDate {
    LocalDateTime getCurrentDate(){
    LocalDateTime openDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    Date closeDate = null ;//= new Date();
    System.out.println("Current date: "+openDate);
    return openDate;
    }
    Date getClosingDate(){
    Date closingDate = null;
  System.out.println("Closing date: "+closingDate);
  return closingDate;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  UpdateDate ud = new UpdateDate();
  ud.getCurrentDate();
  ud.getClosingDate();
 }
}

Comment: I have added sample program below for you to get some idea about your assignment @NMagnus

Comment: `Date` is mutable meaning that another part of the program may alter it against intentions after calling a getter or setter. The good solution is to use `Instant` or `LocalDate`, they are immutable and thus safe. If you insist on the outdated `Date` class, for production code you would need to copy the `Date` defensively in each getter and setter.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find sample program below to get Date with current time when you calling along with closing date as null,

```
public class UpdateDate {

    LocalDateTime getCurrentDate(){
    LocalDateTime openDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("Current date: "+openDate);
    return openDate;
}
Date getClosingDate(){
    Date closingDate = null;
    System.out.println("Closing date: "+closingDate);
    return closingDate;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UpdateDate ud = new UpdateDate();
    ud.getCurrentDate();
    ud.getClosingDate();
}
```

}

it produce below output and you can change it to whatever the format you like using format and parsing methods from Date class in java.

```
output 

Current date: 2018-08-22T18:55:35.906
Closing date: null
```